# Get information about splayd

Tags: distributed-computing, luabind

I am using the SPLAY simulator for distributed applications and I want to submit a simple program that show a message and some info about the splayd that executes that function(like ID, name etc.) but I don't know how to get information about the splayds. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Also my aplication is in Lua language. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. I use job.position for my ID, job.me.ip for my IP and other attributes.
Thanks.